# Добавление данных в datagridview с помощью EF

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework

Всем привет.

Возникло непонимание, связанное с добавлением данных в datagridview.

Мне нужно заставить dgrv использовать данные которые я выбираю из таблицы. То-есть выборка происходит не из всех столбцов а только из нужных мне. А потом запихнуть по нужным столбцам
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код:

```
_context.Flights.Select(s => new
            {
                s.NumberFlight,
                s.Route.FromWhere,
                s.Route.Where,
                s.Route.Incoming,
                s.Route.Departure,
                s.AirlinePlane.SendingAirline,
                s.AirlinePlane.Airplane.Model
            })
            .Load();

            dataGridView1.DataSource = _context.Flights.Local.ToBindingList();
```

Comment: А что здесь именно не так? Подозреваю, что вместо `s.NumberFlight,` надо `NumberFlight = s.NumberFlight,` и далее в том же духе.

Comment: Я не знаю как я могу распихнуть все те данные которые я выбрал, в соответствующие столбцы. То-есть: 
s.NumberFlight запихнуть в столбец ID  и т.д.

Comment: У каждой колонки, если мне память не изменяет, есть свойство DataMember, туда надо списать имя свойства с данными. Либо включить автогенерацию колонок.

Comment: А авто генерация мне не подходит. Так как будут столбцы, которые мне нужны

Comment: Откуда они возьмутся если вы ненужное выбрасываете прямо в запросе?